# Roll back AngularCLI version from 1.0.0-beta.30 to 1.0.0-beta.26 globally?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

After running these:

```
npm uninstall -g angular-cli @angular/cli
npm cache clean
npm install -g angular-cli@1.0.0-beta.26
```

Then, I tried this:

```
ng --version
```

This was my result:

```
angular-cli: 1.0.0-beta.26
node: 7.2.1
os: darwin x64
@angular/cli: 1.0.0-beta.30
@angular/common: 2.4.7
@angular/compiler: 2.4.7
@angular/core: 2.4.7
@angular/forms: 2.4.7
@angular/http: 2.4.7
@angular/material: 2.0.0-beta.1
@angular/platform-browser: 2.4.7
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic: 2.4.7
@angular/router: 3.4.7
@angular/compiler-cli: 2.4.7
```

As you can see @angular/cli: 1.0.0-beta.30 is still there. I'm running this on a MacOSX.

Any help on this will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
npm uninstall -g angular-cli @angular/cli
```

Flag **-g** means that you removed it globably you should also do

```
npm uninstall angular-cli @angular/cli --save-dev
npm install angular-cli@1.0.0-beta.26 --save-dev
```

This will remove packages from your local installation and save changes to  package.json

Comment: @user875139 why what ?:)

Comment: Lol. Quick Question, is there a way I can find the default devDependencies and dependencies that came with this version of the cli?

Comment: I am always looking here https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/package.json. In addition after i am upgrading angular cli, i am doing node_modules delete and then npm install to make sure that i am getting latest dependencies

Comment: Wow, thank you so much! This information is hard to find especially considering its so new.